# How to add forgot password link in WP-Members plugin?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use the WP-Members plugin to register users on a WordPress site but I have no idea how to add a forgot password link in login form?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the forgot password using the shortcode:

password
[wpmem_form password]

The password parameter will generate a password reset form for users who are not logged in and a change password form for logged in users.  It can be used in conjunction with the logged-in and/or logged-out status shortcodes as well.

NOTE: These functions are also a component of the [wpmem_profile] shortcode, so if you have a user profile page already established, you do not need this page as well.  This shortcode is for site admins that might desire a more granular level of control over how these elements are used.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>" title="Lost Password">Lost Password</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The plugin adds a lost password link automatically when the location of the User Profile page is set in the plugin's main options.

Answer (score 0):

As said by bulterblog when u create a new page and add [wpmem_profile] shortcode it will automatically add the forgot password link to the pages/post which you have blocked.